# Plot with Histogram an attribute from a dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib

I have a ***dataframe*** with the **weight** and the **number of measures** of each user. The df looks like:

| id_user | weight | number_of_measures |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 92.16 | 4 |
| 2 | 80.34 | 5 |
| 3 | 71.89 | 11 |
| 4 | 81.11 | 7 |
| 5 | 77.23 | 8 |
| 6 | 92.37 | 2 |
| 7 | 88.18 | 3 |

I would like to see an histogram with the attribute of the table (weight, but I want to do it for both cases) at the **x-axis** and the frequency in the **y-axis**.

### [image]

Does anyone know how to do it with matplotlib?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems to be quite easy:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hist = df.hist(bins=50)
plt.show()
```